# SQL MATCH ignoring the word WELCOME

Tags: mysql, sql, match

I have a strange issue.
I have a database with keywords assigned to the products for example...

Product 839126 has the keywords PREMIUM,COIR,RUBBER,WELCOME,DOOR,MATS,HOMEWARES,DOORMATS,FLOOR

The following SQL returns relevance as 0 if I choose the word `Welcome` any other keyword and relevance is 1

```
SELECT  pb2b_products.id,
        item_code,
        item_name_1,
        item_name_2,
        keywords,
        MATCH (`item_name_1`,`item_name_2`,`keywords`) AGAINST ('WELCOME' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance

        FROM pb2b_products 
                LEFT JOIN pb2b_products_content ON pb2b_products_content.id = pb2b_products.id 
                LEFT JOIN pb2b_products_stock ON pb2b_products_stock.id = pb2b_products.id 
                LEFT JOIN pb2b_users_orders ON pb2b_users_orders.item_id = pb2b_products.id
                LEFT OUTER JOIN pb2b_uri ON pb2b_uri.uri_key = pb2b_products.id 
        
        WHERE   pb2b_uri.uri_act = '3'
        AND     item_code = '839126'
        ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

Does anyone have any ideas on why this might be happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very important concept in using full text search is the concept of "stop words".  These are words that are automatically ignored when the inverted index is created.  You can investigate this concept in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html).

`'WELCOME'` is a common stop word.  It is in the default stop word lists for both InnoDB and MyISAM.

You can recreate the index with either customized stop words or no stop words at all.  Note that there are other considerations as well, such as characters that define word boundaries and minimum word length.